# Optimising Delivery of CSS as recommended by Google

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, seo

I've been running my site through Google's site speed tester

(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

and trying to fix all the issues that were found. One major issue which was highlighted red as a must fix issue is:

**"Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"**

**"Optimise Delivery of CSS"** & **"Remove render-blocking JavaScript:"**

I started off by combining some of my CSS files together to reduce the amount of calls to external css files in my < head > tags and I added "defer" to all of my javascript calls apart from the jquery.min.js one as this must be called first.

This fixed some of the examples Google was telling me to fix. But I am still left with more. I read that placing your CSS within your HTML inside the < head > tags fixes this issue. However my CSS comes to about 18,000 lines in total and this was not an option for me.

However it dawned on me that I could use PHP includes to include my .css files in my < head > instead of the traditional method for calling them.

So now I call my CSS like this:

```
<style><?php include "css/style.min.css";?></style>
```

instead of like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.min.css">
```

This keeps my code short and neat and Google seems to love it. My site is now picking up a 90/100 for desktop and 86/100 for mobile phones.

The issue I have is that the source code for my pages is now truly massive because of including the CSS and Javascript.

Will this have any unforeseen negative SEO effects or an effect on my website's performance in the eyes of search engines?

Is what I have done frowned upon?

Comment: I would not include the website's CSS in the `<style>` tag. You are increasing the filesize of every webpage of your site and the CSS does not get cached. Using `<link>` and setting the proper headers will get your CSS cached. On the first visit there will be a slight drop in performance when the file is first downloaded. Upon additional and future page visits that file will be available in the cache (immediately). So no, I would not do what you have done. Move JS files right before the closing `</body>` tag if you can, this includes your jQuery, include it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main disadvantage with your new approach is that if you include the CSS and the JS in the head of your file, you minimize DNS lookups (this could help to get a better ranking on Google speed test) but all your source code won't be cached by the browser (as it will be downloaded again on page request).
So if your user visits other pages of your website which may utilize the same resources, they could experience a slow responsiveness.

If a considerable amount of users leave your website because of long waiting, this is not Good for your site, also in terms of SEO as Bounce rate would be higher and affect your overall ranking.

My advice:

- Minify and concatenate JS and CSS.
- Do not embed the code in the `<head>`; instead, use `<link>`.
- If your JavaScript and CSS files are huge, you need to use a modular approach (ex: using AMD for JS). You can append the `<link>` tag also for CSS on the fly when you need it (look at some [library examples](https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle)).
- If you use common JS libraries like jQuery consider using a popular CDN.

Comment: Minimising DNS lookups does seem to please Google. I guess it's because the less lookups there are the quicker your page loads. But then maybe this gets cancelled out by the fact that your browser has to load all that CSS and JS code on every page load if you do what I have done.

I have concatenated all of my CSS and JS already. (that was actually a separate issue Google wanted me to fix)

I get the impression my new method is not recommended so I will change back to <link> instead

I will look into your suggestions for appending <link> tags on the fly as my CSS files are huge.

Thank you